# RabbitMQ vs GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cluster-computing, rabbitmq

I'm programming a real-time mobile game that exchanges messages in real time and I would like to know what should I choose from: RabbitMQ or GAE. I know that GAE is a solution that works and makes my programming much faster since almost everything is already implemented, but on a long run I don't know if I'm willing to pay those really high prices - so it comes down to implementing some other message exchange service on my own servers, so I'm thinking about RabbitMQ.

The thing that worries me is that the RabbitMQ nodes can be added to a cluster, but if GAE uses 1.000 instances, how much RabbitMQ nodes would it take to handle the same load, because I really don't want to have 1.000 nodes in a cluster, which means I have to rent 1.000 VPSs.

So, that is why I'm trying to determine how much rabbitmq nodes (in a cluster) would it take to handle 1 million of users. I'm trying to compare that to Google Appengine Instances. Let's say my application on GAE should process the following: 
  - 10.000 requests/second 
  - 1000 instances running

I know we can't really compare those, but let's do it anyway. I want to know the following questions:

**1. I want to handle 10.000 requests/s (each request needs to be a permanent connection that takes at least 1-10 minutes):**

a) How many GAE instances would be needed for that to be feasible?

b) How many nodes in a cluster would be needed with RabbitMQ for it to work?

**2. I want a comparison to RabbitMQ with 1.000 GAE instances:**

a) How much work can 1 GAE instance do compared to 1 cluster node in RabbitMQ?

**3. What would you choose:**

a) I know you'll all say GAE, because it's really easy, already is prepared, etc.

b) But then again, are we willing to pay all that. Not to mention that Google has some restrictions as the author is talking about them here: http://www.carlosble.com/2010/11/goodbye-google-app-engine-gae/ .

Thanks for all the valuable answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GAE is not comparable to RabbitMQ to the extent that your question barely makes sense. RabbitMQ is just messaging, and you'd most likely have to set up more infrastructure to support your use cases. GAE is a full infrastructure. That said, RabbitMQ can process an impressive amount of messages per second.

Maybe you want to make an API for the mobile game to connect to, and some application logic to go with those messages. You won't let the game clients connect to your RabbitMQ server and talk directly to other clients.

On GAE you normally have requests and immediate responses. If you need connections that last longer and allows you to push messages to game client (not using APN etc) you might want to consider XMPP or websockets, so you'd need something else in addition to or instead of GAE anyway. [Cloud Endpoints](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4) might also be worth a look.

Several of the limitations mentioned in the blog article have been resolved by now.

I think you need to work more on your requirements and architecture, and as you do that you will get a better idea about technology choices. Choosing a specific AMQP server like RabbitMQ is a decision you make after you've decided to use messaging, how to use messaging, seeing that AMQP works as messaging solution (ZeroMQ, XMPP are some alternatives), and need to find a fast and efficient AMQP server.

Comment: Hi. First let's me just say that yeah, we can't really compare GAE to RMQ, but I would still like to know a more detailed answer about GAE instances - how powerful is each one of them, how many requests can it handle compared to RMQ. And yes, I've already decides to use messaging, but now I have to make sure that it can scale as beautifly as GAE.

Comment: Some useless and inaccurate musings without any solid data to back it up: A GAE instance can probably process between 1 and 400 requests a second, depending on parallelism, IO usage and how well you adapt to the platform. A single RMQ instance can probably process between 4000 and 20000 messages a second, and you can set up clustering for more.

Comment: Hi tesdal, if you can come up with a real answer, thus answering with some numbers (maybe with CPU/RAM/Disk comparison) as accurate as they can be, I'd be more than happy to accept your answer, since that's exactly what I'm asking. And btw: the numbers you already presented are really what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guy using RMQ on EC2 and reporting "RabbitMQ doing 28k/sec in-out direct messaging, 70k/sec fanout on an m1.xlarge".

https://twitter.com/rbranson/status/220399933583396865

Comment: Hi, the answer is really not much of a hassle from your part. You should probably compare the two technologies that I mentioned, not just post a link to some twitter feed.